# Brothers & sisters

Tags: steganography

I love my family so much, they are so strong and lovely. I wrote something about them to show the world who I really love:

> My mother restless, somehow winning glamorously
>   Hella brother and deadass sisters
>   Father roasted dumb bully, yet the evil is lurking
>   Nothing stops sisterhood, don't try
>   The evil lurks, but siblings stand
>   Unite! Evil lets sisters sing a glorious song
>   Family, you supersized unity!
>   A baby all losers, superb bullies, stay, yet tenacious siblings shine endlessly

Comment: Hi and welcome to Puzzling SE! This is a nicely framed first question! Also, is the answerer supposed to answer *"Who do I love the most?"* or something else?

Comment: The answer tells you something about who I love how much, but it isn't just a name or something

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> My brother is nothing but a supersized baby

since,

> the last letter of most words chains to the first letter of the next word, with the exceptions of words surrounding "MY", "BROTHER", "IS", "NOTHING", "BUT", "A", "SUPERSIZED", and "BABY".

Plus,

> removing those words restores the letter chain.

Comment: Ninjaed by one minute.

Comment: Well that was quick, you almost got it

Comment: Revised, somehow overlooked a couple of words in typing my answer even though I had them highlighted.

Comment: Perfect! I already figured thus would be easy but rot13(zl oebgure jbag trg vg naljnl)